# Can a creature that can't understand any languages understand the languages of a creature that can't speak if it is polymorphed?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, polymorph, languages

[An earlier question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/206170/magic-items-spells-with-my-displacer-beast-kitten) about a creature that can't speak(a displacer beast) got me thinking: what if the creature was polymorphed into a creature that could understand languages but couldn't speak, such as a pseudodragon?

> ***Polymorph.*** This spell transforms a creature that you can see within range into a new form.

...

> The transformation lasts for the duration

(The duration is 1 hour.)

...

> The creature can't ... speak.

Comment: It should be noted that a pseudodragon is not an eligible choice for *polymorph*, but there may be other valid examples for the question.

Comment: Heavily related, possibly dupe: [Can a Druid understand a new form's languages only while Wildshaped into it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71070/63795), [Is language tied to statistics, ability scores, and/or skill proficiencies according to the rules?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71106/63795)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### A creature can understand the languages stated in its statblock.

The rules for monster game statistics state:

> The languages that a monster can speak are listed in alphabetical order. Sometimes a monster can understand a language but can’t speak it, and this is noted in its entry. A “ — ” indicates that a creature neither speaks nor understands any language.

So if the polymorph form’s statblock has a language listed, the creature can understand that language, since the creature’s statistics are replaced by those of the polymorph form:

> The target's game statistics, including mental ability scores, are replaced by the statistics of the chosen beast.